# NoClassDefFoundError occuring when i upgraded compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, gradle

When I upgraded compileSdkVersion and tergetSdkVersion to 25, showing this error;

- E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'ExampleActivity', referenced from method MainActivity.onClick

And I reduced version to 23, error is;

- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Here is my activity ;

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
   }
}
```

My gradle file; (this project is library project, I did not write it wrong.)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
   }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: put all your code here, including your Activity.

Comment: Please read it carefully, not a duplicate question. --Edited my question @LuizFernandoSalvaterra .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct your dependency also:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

check it after replace this in your app level gradle dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that really helps to use latest libraries is here:

```
//this will initialize multidex in your own Application class
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
super.attachBaseContext(base);
MultiDex.install(this);}
```

Comment: I tried this , not working. Thanks.